# Pass parameters from one form to another and add new records

Tags: ms-access

I want:

To be able to open a form, select an item from a control box, click a button to open a new form and be able to input new records that have the previously selected item added to their fields.

What I have done so far:

I have made two forms, added the controls in both, added a command button.
I have used MS Access wizard to add this code:

```
Private Sub CommandNext_Click()
  On Error GoTo Err_CommandNext_Click

    Dim stDocName As String
    Dim stLinkCriteria As String

    stDocName = "FormX"
    DoCmd.OpenForm stDocName, , , "[BatchID] = " & Me![ListBatch], acFormAdd

  Exit_CommandNext_Click:

    Exit Sub

  Err_CommandNext_Click:

    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume Exit_CommandNext_Click

End Sub
```

The third line is mine.

As a result:

- If the second form **isn't** already open, pressing the button on the first form will open the second one with empty data (the text field that should show the value of the parameter is empty).
- If the second form **is** already open, pressing the button on the first form will change focus to the second one and it will show an old, existing record that matches the parameter I selected
- I want to open the second form without any old records showing but with the selected parameter appearing in the designated text field.

In both cases in the second form the *Filter* property gets populated with the parameter I've sent using the button, but that isn't what I am aiming for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you aware the 4th argument for the open form command is the where condition or filter to apply?

If you use the last parameter which is called open arguments (OpenArgs) then you can write code in the 2nd forms open event to set the default value for the column in question.

The open form code would look something like this:

```
DoCmd.OpenForm stDocName, , , , acFormAdd, , Me![ListBatch]
```

You could then put code similar to the following in this 2nd forms open event:

```
Dim defaultID as Long
defaultID = CLng(Nz(Me.OpenArgs, 0))
If defaultID = 0 Or IsNull(Me.OpenArgs) Then
    Cancel = True
    Exit Sub
End If
Me.TextBoxBatchID.DefaultValue = defaultID
```

Or if you do not need the ID to be set for every new record you could just set the current value of the control to the defaultID variable.

```
 Me.TextBoxBatchID = defaultID
```

Please note the code above would not open the form if the open argument turned out to be empty or 0.

Comment: I will try it in a bit. Just wanted to express my surprise that I didn't find about that the first time I read about OpenForm on msdn.microsoft.com . Even after you told me what it is I still had hard time to understand what Microsoft has written about it. Additional question - can I pass multiple arguments the way explained here http://www.fmsinc.com/free/newtips/access/accesstip13.asp or is there an easier way?

Comment: Yes technical descriptions can be a bit dry to say the least.

I think that the link shows the easiest way to send multiple arguments in the open arguments parameter.  You can of course use any character you wish as the delimiter provided it is not contained within the data values you are sending.